# ClickOnce deployment installs, but doesn't run

Tags: clickonce

I have been working on an application for several years. It has been distributed via ClickOnce from the very beginning. I recently pushed out an update using the same process I have been using for years. This time, however, the application isn't running. The system detects that there is an update and downloads the new bits. Then, nothing. The ClickOnce install log, in temp inet files folder, shows success.

Interestingly, if you browse to the executable in the appdata path, and run it directly, it will run. And, it seems, after launching it directly, it will then run from the installed icon as it always has. I don't know if this is somehow related to the recent Windows updates, but I can't figure out how to troubleshoot this so that the install completes and runs the app without intervention. And I don't want to ask the IT folks to visit every machine and run through the process of launching the app directly to "reconnect" it to the icon, or whatever.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Did some looking and it appears the latest updated modified how windows defender works

According to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/954ad3f0-a718-4443-86fd-49877abd130f/after-a-clickonce-application-update-application-wont-start, Windows defender won't show the warning message for untrusted ClickOnce apps when they are launched.

Opening "Windows Defender Security Center" and turning "Check apps and files" to "Off" allows the app to be ran. After it has been ran once the setting can restored and the app will continue to be allowed to run.

I think the real solution here is signing the application correctly so windows doesn't flag it as untrusted, I'll report back if that also helps.